# Sliding scale discounts formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

I feel like there must be an easy way to calculate the following:

```
1 item = $10
2 items = $10 + ($10 * 0.9 * 1)
3 items = $10 + ($10 * 0.9 * 2)
4 items = $10 + ($10 * 0.9 * 2) + ($10 * 0.8 * 1)
```

In other words, offer a discount of 10% for the 2nd and 3rd items, 20% for the 4th-10th items, maybe 50% for the 11th+ item.

I'm looking for more than calculating how many items at each discount tier and applying the discount to each group, rather, is there a way to go about this in a single "pass"?

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean by "in a single 'pass'". Would a piecewise defined function, with 3 pieces, suffice?

Comment: I mean not storing the counts for each day in separate variables and then multiplying and adding up. This is thinking as a programmer not a mathematician so it might not make sense, I'm not sure.

Comment: I would argue that calculating how many items there are at each tier and applying the discount to the group is a superior approach, not from a math standpoint but from a software maintenance standpoint.  It will be easy to explain and understand what you are doing that way and easier to update when you change the discount schedule.  If we could give you a magic formula that got just the discounts you specify you would likely be locked into that schedule forever or be stuck with schedules that only change the constants in the formula.

Comment: Recreational mathematics?

Comment: Well not sure what qualifies for recreational math, but the purpose of the question is for entertainment purposes only. As @RossMillikan points out, there is a better practical way than a one-size-fits-all formula.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what functions you're going to allow yourself.  If we can use "max" (a function available in any spreadsheet) then it's not too bad:

$$p(n) = 10n - \max(n-1,0) - \max(n-3,0) - 3\max(n-10,0).$$

If you don't want max, then it's possible to pass a (very ugly) polynomial through the points, or maybe a Pade approximation.  Or perhaps max can be replaced by Heaviside functions...?

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding or my problem is not clear enough, but I can't see how that formula takes into account the discounts at each tier. But it did give me an idea to try (and will report back). I can use pretty much any function I want, just looking for the most elegant way to solve this.

Comment: Try plugging in a few values for $n$ in my formula.  You'll see it gives the right answer, and maybe doing the calculations will help you see why it works.

Comment: Thanks B, I tried with 4, which should total 36 which the formula gets right, but if I try say 12, the formula gives 98, but it should be 89.

Comment: If your intent is that the first item is 10 and the 2nd and 3rd are 9, that's 28 dollars.  Items 4 to 10 makes 7 items at 8 dollars, which is 56.  The 11th and 12th items are 7 each so that 14 more.  Then 28+56+14 = 98.

Comment: Rats, of course, I didn't fully explain the formula and it seems the scale is linear but it's not, the 11th and 12th items would actually be $5 each.

Comment: Which makes the total 94 dollars.  To fix my formula, I just stick a $3$ in front of the last "max".  I'll edit.